# What's "incompatible with the angles you have in your drawing, specifically these stripes all terminate at the roof ridge"?

Tags: critique

I don't understand [this part of leftaroundabout's critique](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/142907/why-do-these-angles-look-weird-in-my-logo). I don't know what "*roof ridge*" means — is this my red line? What exactly is the hitch here? English ISN'T my first language.

[image]

> Next, you add some stripes – evidently you do this on the side wall...
>
> [image: lines on side]
>
> ...and continuing onto the roof
>
> [image: lines on s+r]
>
> But that already is *incompatible* with the angles you have in your drawing, specifically these stripes all terminate at the *roof ridge* and therefore should all have inline-cut ends, like so:
>
> [image: polygon form of side/roof lines]
>
> (At this point, a “growing towards the back” illusion does seem to creep in, but IMO still not problematic.)

Comment: [What is a roof ridge?](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+a+roof+ridge&ei=HZqUYbD0ObTB0PEPpre4kAc&oq=what+is+a+roof+ridge&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAoQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB46BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6BggAEAcQHjoICAAQCBAHEB46BAgAEA1KBQhAEgExSgQIQRgAUPMGWJAKYOEPaAJwAXgAgAF5iAHCA5IBAzAuNJgBAKABAcgBCcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjw9o3l2570AhW0IDQIHaYbDnIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)

Comment: Maybe check a roofing website?  Such as this one: [What are the different parts of a roof](https://www.marley.co.uk/blog/what-are-the-different-parts-of-a-roof#:~:text=What%20are%20the%20different%20parts%20of%20a%20roof%3F,%28also%20called%20rafters%20or%20common%20rafters%29.%20More%20items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User leftroundabout tells that all 3 bars between the roof top and the ground line should be drawn in the same way for less disturbing look. That's an opinion and should be respected as much as opinions in other answers. His "ridge" is the roof top line. You have drawn in red the imagined border where the wall meets the edge of the roof.

Leftroundabout admits that someone can also see some disturbing apparent enlargening towards the right (=the main point in another answer, also an opinion) but he says it doesn't disturb him.